# Cipher.WRAP_MODE vs Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE

Tags: java, aes, encryption

Is there any difference/benefits/draw backs from using Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE
to encrypt a Secret Key for transmission over using Cipher.WRAP_MODE?

My understanding is that I still need to have a second, possibly less secret key to either wrap/encrypt and unwrap/decrypt the Secret Key
And if i use CBC Mode... i need to supply the unique IV for both as well....

so whats the difference/point of WRAP and UNWRAP?

BTW.. I'm using AES Encryption

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this: http://flylib.com/books/en/1.274.1.29/1/ It's explanation of what Cipher.WRAP_MODE and Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE does and how it differs from doing it on your own.

Comment: From the article: "purpose-built key-wrapping mechanism includes an integrity check that is used to ensure that the key probably decrypted properly." is the answer I was looking for, thanks :-)